# UserDefault new syntax in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to do a code like this:

```
the key "firstUseValue" exists?
if it does:
    is valueForKey("firstUseValue") true?
        print("USING FOR THE FIRST TIME")
        setValueForKey("firstUseValue", false)
    else
        print("I HAVE BEEN USED BEFORE")
if it doesn't:
    create bool for key "firstUseValue" with value true
    print("USING FOR THE FIRST TIME")
```

but since NSUserDefault was changed to UserDefaults (in swift), I wasn't able to write a single line of code without compilation errors (that I could not understand).

How can I write this code using UserDefaults correctly?

Comment: Here is easy explanation using Swift 5 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMIx7H4u4lg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 2**

```
// Set
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(123, forKey: "key")
// Get
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")
```

**Swift 3**

```
// Set
UserDefaults.standard.set(123, forKey: "key")
// Get
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "key")
```

For the set you can specify what you need, Bool, String, Float etc.
[image]

Comment: You are passing an optional String instead of an integer

Comment: You are setting an String and trying to load an Integer for that key

Comment: how do i check if the value is defined given a key (String) ?

Comment: Thats not true it would return 0. If you need to know if the key exits you need to use objectForKey method

Comment: That´s true, though they removed it, @Daniel use the following row `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key")`if it returns `nil`then it´s empty.